# Using javascript fetch api in codeigniter4 results in "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Basically i wanted to implement Webauthn into my login, but i can't even get this to work. So i don't need to bother about Webauthn. Maybe someone can point me into the right direction.

**View:**

```
<script>
   window.onload = function(){
      document.getElementById('loginform').addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);
   };

   function onSubmit() {
      var register=document.getElementById('register').checked;

   fetch('register', {
       method: "get",
       headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
         "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
       }
     })
     .then(function (data) {
       console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log('Request failed', error);
     });
   }
</script>
```

**Routes.php:**

```
$routes->get('/', 'Login::index');
$routes->post('login', 'Login::login');
$routes->post('register', 'Login::register');
$routes->get('register', 'Login::register');
$routes->add('logoff', 'Login::logoff');
```

**Controller (login.php):**

```
    public function register () {
        log_message('info', 'register called');
        $data ="yeah yeah";
        return $this->response->setJSON($data);
    }
```

Comment: what does the full error message say? Put it into your question and format it, rather than just putting what looks like part of it into the title. Thanks.

Comment: Also, did you try to debug this with the browser's network tool to see what might have happened to the fetch request? Your question is all-round a bit vague and lacking technical detail.

Answer (score 0):

here is what i changed in the view:

```
   window.fetch('register.php', {
```

then i created a register.php file in the public folder of codeigniter4:

```
$handle = fopen('register.log', "w");
fwrite($handle, 'called');
fclose($handle);

 $data = 'yeah yeah';
 print(json_encode($data));
```

Guess what. Its working now, even writing the log file into the public folder.

Now the question remains, how to run this within the framework by using the Controller i wanted to use (login::register).

Bypassing all the framework and simply executing the script is not what i expected.